# How to check if SSAS service is responding

Tags: server, ssas, olap

Is there a way to check if analysis service installed on a server is not responding and it requires a restart ? 
I been looking at SSAS DMVS :

- SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_CONNECTIONSGO
- Select * from $System.discover_object_memory_usage
- Select * from $System.discover_locks

but I dont feel like they answer my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Here MSSQLServerOLAPService is the name of SQL Analysis service and can be found from [image: Here]

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'querystate',N'MSSQLServerOLAPService'
```

You can check the status of your service and take decision accordingly.

Comment: Hey, if this answer is a solution to your problem, please accept it and up-vote it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately the Service state does not change when the service does not respond it still shows status "Running." so I cannot take action solely on this check.

Comment: May be this can solve your problem automatically without any of your manual efforts.: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972777

Comment: Thank's for your help I will check that post out , Have a nice day :)